# C# linq map composite dictionary with list

Tags: c#, linq

I have one composite dictionary and one list

```
Dictionary<Point, List<int>> GroupedIndex
List<double> TobeMatched
```

Now I want to create new dictionary with same key but with Values mapped by corresponding index from the GroupedIndex int values with TobeMatched index

```
Example:
```

> GroupedIndex: [0] -> Key [X=1;Y=1]; Values [0] -> 5, [1] -> 10
>
> TobeMatched: [0] 0.23 [5] 0.345 [10] 1.23

```
Result expected:
New dictionary: [0] -> Key[X=1;Y=1]; Values [0] -> 0.345, [1] -> 1.23
```

is it possible to linq to achieve the result efficiently. For loop is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GroupedIndex.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                              x => x.Value.Select(y=>TobeMatched[y]).ToList());
```

That's how you do this with LINQ. But I doubt it will be faster compared to regular loops.

Comment: Excellent answer. Shows how good LINQ is for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, LINQ to objects allows very succint expressions for collection filtering, sorting and projection (transformation). And after some experience with F#'s modules like `List` or `Seq` it's hard to live without it. But performance-wise sometimes it isn't the best answer, and the question was about 'efficiency'...

Comment: I think the efficiency of the coder is often more important that the efficiency of the code. Optimize for going home early than for saving a handful of milliseconds of compute time.

Comment: @Enigmativity and here I can't disagree with you. 8)

Comment: @Dmitry: Thanks for the quick reply. But as your said, it is very slow than for loop.

Comment: @Suresh As far as I know, internally LINQ to objects uses loops too. But it's also have to interpret an Expression tree which actually makes it slower. You can try PLINQ (`GroupedIndex.AsParallel().ToDictionary(...)`). Also you can remove `ToList()` from that my example, that way it will create a `Dictionary<Point, IEnumerable<double>>` and won't execute mapping right away, so it will be executed only when you access it. It's known as deferred execution and might come in handy if you don't access every pair in that dictionary.

Comment: @Dmitry: Unfortunately Iam using VS2008. PLINQ is not available. As you said, I need to access only one pair for further processing. Can I group using element index? Eg. `GroupedIndex.ElementAt(n)` to get the list with doubles for matching row index.

Comment: @Dmitry: You made my day. my requirement is to process each element. I am now processing using single element and it works like charm!!!!